# Computer won't power on after adding my old SSD to my new computer

Tags: desktop-computer, storage, build

I am having some trouble with connecting my old SSD (intel SSD 520 series 240gb) to my new computer.

When I plugged the drive into the motherboard and the power supply (separate 6 pin SATA connector from the rest of my storage.) and tried to turn the computer on nothing happened. There was a bit of a click, but that was it. Pressing the power button subsequently resulted in no sounds being made.

I tried some different approaches to try and find the problem such as;

1. Only connecting the power cable to the SSD; it still wouldn't power on
2. Using a different SATA connecter; no change.
3. Disconnecting my HDD in order to use the power cable from that HDD to power the SSD; resulted in the pc starting (Not ideal, since I want to connect both of them).

I am worried that my PSU just can't supply enough power, but I really doubt that's the problem.

Does anyone know what I should do? Or have been in a similar situation?

Specs:

Cpu:
Intel Core i7-10700KF op til 5.1GHz

GPU:
Asus Rog STRIX RTX 2080TI 11VGB

Motherboard:
Asus TUF Gaming Z490-Plus (M. WIFI)

RAM:
32GB G.Skill TridentZ RGB 3000MHz

Primary storage:
500 GB Samsung 970 EVO

Secondary storage::
Toshiba hdwd110 (1TB)

PSU:
850w 80+ Gold Riotoro G2 Enigma

Comment: If you disconnect only the 240GB SSD, and hook up everything else the way you want it, does the computer power on and work 100%?

Comment: Yes it does, it works perfectly fine

Comment: You cannot run the SSD this way, but what happens if you connect the SATA cable but not the power cable to the drive?

Comment: I haven't tried that. But what am i doing wrong with the SSD? 
The way I see it, troubles comes when i connect the SSD to the PSU. But i kinda have to use a separate power cable for the SSD; due to all the other power ports being used on the other SATA power cable. Am i wrong?

Comment: I don't think you are doing anything wrong, but is somehow seems the old drive power is not compatible with the new computer. I do not know precisely why. 850 Watt PSU is not short of power.  Can you try with one PSU (maybe disconnect one peripheral)?  This is just a learning exercise until you know more.

Comment: Ahh i see, so a "guaranteed" solution would be to buy a new SSD?

Comment: This is something worth trying for sure. Then somehow get the data from the old drive.

Comment: I actually do not care about the data. I just intend to use the storage space for a ubuntu dual-boot.

Comment: One thing i do not understand tho: When i disconnect the HDD, and use its powerport for the SSD, the pc starts.

Comment: There is a power issue at hand. Either the PSU is stretched to the limit (literally) or there is some other power issue at play.

Comment: Also even though i have 850 Watt PSU? Could it really be stretched to the limit?

Comment: You disconnected the Hard Drive, connected the SSD and it worked.  There may be an issue with the Power Supply. It is truly a power issue overall.

Comment: Is there any other solution then to get a PSU with more Watt then?

Comment: Something like that.  Or remove a lesser used peripheral.

Comment: I just ued a PSU calculator (https://outervision.com/power-supply-calculator) to approximate how stretched my PSU should be. 

Using this calculator, i should only be using 527 Watt.

Do u think that this calculator could be right? I just really dont want to upgrade to a 1000Watt PSU

Comment: 850 w should be more than enough power for what you are running.

Comment: There could be an internal error in the supply that is causing this.

Comment: *"PSU: 850w 80+ Gold Riotoro G2 Enigma"* -- That's a PSU with modular connectors.  So you know that two SATA power connectors are good.  You know that the *"old SSD"* does work with the HDD's power connection.  But you haven't mentioned if you have connected anything other than the *"old SSD"* to any other SATA power connectors, i.e. the *"separate power cable"*.  So the issue seems to boil down to finding a good 3rd SATA power connector.  Using the base configuration that you listed under *"specs"*, test whatever additional SATA power connectors there are besides the original two.